# Selecting the Right GPIOs

Tags: esp8266, pins, relay

I've bought this 4 relay ESP8266 board to active lights and window shades.

In an odd way - its relays are not pre-connected to a certain IO's but let you choose which IOs will operate relays (by jumpering desired IOs). See Item below.

[image: pic1].[image: pic2]

To operate my design, 4 inputs and 4 outputs are needed.

Exposed IOs are: `io0`,`io2`,`io4`,`io5`,`io12`,`io13`,`io14`,`io15`,`io16`.

while 9 IOs available only 8 are needed. I use [randomnerdtutorials](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-pinout-reference-gpios/).[image: table]

Misfits:

1. `io0` and `io2` can not serve as inputs since switch will fail boot (designed inputs are toggles),
2. `io16` and `io2` as outputs, are `HIGH` on boot, causing it to turn on for a fraction of second every boot (which turns on light or sliding window shades) - which I want to avoid.

which leaves:

1. Inputs: `io16`, `io5`,`io4`,`io13`
2. Outputs: `io0`,`io14`,`io12`,`io15`

Questions:

1. Is pins selection is OK ?
2. Why `io15` is colored yellow and will it affect its use as an output?

3.`io16` the only will be OK as input ?

4.`io0` as an output (Relay)? since at reset all relays are powered off (want to be sure).

Comment: For Question 2, I guess GPIO15 is yellow because the pin must be low at boot time. It would be OK, for example, to power a led which is wired on the LOW side but not to sink one wired on the HIGH side. 
Question 3 is not very clear.

Comment: why is "misfit 1" an issue? If you write your own code, you can ignore inputs during startup and choose the startup condition yourself.

Comment: @6v6gt Question2: Will it /Can it affect an output ? I guess not ( so why is it yellow ? ), Question 3 - table does not say if IO16 if it will fail on boot ( assigning it as input, can be toggled LOW).

Comment: @hennep you are not correct. Boot will fail, no mater what the code will be.

Comment: @guyd, most modern embedded processors can configure pins in software for multiple purposes. So, if you need the I2C serial bus to talk to an external chip you couldn't use GPIO 5 and 4.  But if you don't need to use the I2C bus you can use GPIO 5 and 4.  Is this the type of Answer you were looking for?  Let us know and someone can write up a more complete Answer.

Comment: @guyd A pin is not defined as an output (using pinMode() ) until the boot activity has finished and the sketch begins to run. Important only is that you don't connect anything to the pin which may violate its required startup condition. Hence, for GPIO15, it would be OK to connect a LED between it and the GND power rail because the pin would be LOW at boot time. It would not be OK to connect a LED between the 3.3v rail and GPIO15.

Comment: @st2000 Perhaps I'm not explaining my self correctly. I know `io5` or `io4` can be used as inputs or output, in addition to their I2C role. Never the less, certain IOs as `io0` and `io2` will fail boot if they are set to LOW (as in my case - Toggle switches), regardless if they were defined or not later in code using `pinMode`. Now - all 9 gpios I've got, some fit to be an input (or output) and some are not.

Comment: Since you only need 4 for the relays it does not matter as long as they are not predefined. You can use the A/D and a resistor array as inputs for the buttons. I generally use a I2C an external chip for I/0 such as an PCF8574. The PCF8574 defaults to INPUT on startup which is turning  all the outputs on. My designs use them as active low. That Way during reset etc no glitches. It only sources a very small amount of current but will sink several mills. There are many other devices you can use as well.